# Chrome dev tools (network tab) doesn't reflect aborted requests

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm playing around with `AbortController` in order to cancel requests made with `fetch`. When I call `abort()` I do see my `catch()` handler being called (which means that the request was effectively canceled), but the request itself still retrieves the data from the endpoint (according to Chrome's network tab).

I was expecting the request to be aborted so that no download traffic would occur (assuming that the download of the actual data hasn't happened at the time the `abort()` is called).

Is this the expected behavior of `AbortController`?

As a side question: If "yes, that is the expected behavior, the request isn't aborted in a way to prevent download traffic", is there a way to actually abort a request made with `fetch`?

Edit: I'm testing https://fetch-abort-demo.glitch.me with Chrome and Safari, and while Safari does highlight with red the aborted request, Chrome doesn't. Maybe this is just a Chrome UI bug?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is expected behaviour.

Say you say to me, give me all the nuts from that bag behind you.

I hand you all the nuts scoop by scoop in the bag you are having.
Having been halfway finished emptying my bag into yours, you change your mind, drop the bag on the floor and walk away without saying a word.

Are there still nuts in what was once your bag? Yes, because it takes time to transfer data, and data is delivered in chunks/packets, piece by piece. Only when all the packets are transferred is the transmission complete.

Your request was aborted, but it had been in progress for a while getting packets. You just stopped requesting and accepting packets.

Comment: I do agree with your reasoning, but I explicitly said "assuming that the download of the actual data hasn't happened at the time the abort() is called". So, let's say that I just made the request to the server, but the server never replied in any way (let's say because of high load)

Comment: If the request already has left your browser and arrived at the server in complete, then the server will reply with the full data requested. If the browser doesn't "Drop the connection" due to for example http2 it will accept the full glut of the returned data, but not invoke the response handlers.

Comment: But that still doesn't answer my side question (nor the fact that Safari and Chrome behave differently) (check the update)

Comment: @alexandernst Well if you check the explanation link in the chrome network tab, you end up fairly quickly in the content download part.https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/?utm_source=devtools#timing-explanation From that moment there is a partial download. I suggest you test with something that sends a size as a response, and what happens if the download is incomplete with the expected send size.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length